# View Controllers giving an error when creating a segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I have a navigation controller and the first VC modals into the second one fine. I pressed `ctrl+button` and dragged it over, all works fine.

I am doing a second segue from the first VC (again) and this time its another button, I am `ctrl+button` and dragging it to the new VC and I get an USELESS error in XCODE -

> 2014-03-04 11:57:21.340 OutTonight[3173:60b] -[SettingsViewController
>   setDealdetail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e686d0
>   2014-03-04 11:57:21.342 OutTonight[3173:60b] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[SettingsViewController setDealdetail:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x16e686d0'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Here is my prepareforseguecode

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
      DealViewController *detailView  = (DealViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
      detailView.dealdetail = [self.allcontent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      detailView.dealpostcode = [self.allpostode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      detailView.dealvenuename = [self.allname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      detailView.dealaddress = [self.alladdress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      detailView.dealaddress2 = [self.alladdress2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      detailView.deallat = [self.alllat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      detailView.deallng = [self.alllong objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      detailView.userlatitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserLatitude"];
      detailView.userlongitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserLongitude"];
}
```

Any ideas? [image]

Comment: have you added the UIButton action method? as unrecognised selector means it does not have an associated action method e.g., for UIButton action method attached to UITouchupInside.

Comment: I have not doing anything with the UIButton yet, I have not create an IBAction or anything - I though this could be the problem ? Should I put a

Comment: Created an IBAction for the button in my view controller.h file, still error

Comment: Do you override **prepareForSegue** in the secondViewController

Comment: Can you create an IBAction to the button and in the method call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue identified" sender:self]; and in the method prepareForSegue you can handle the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have done something in `-prepareForSegue:` for the original segue? In which case, you need to make sure you are checking which segue it is in `-prepareForSegue:`, and doing the correct thing for each one.

Edit:

To expand on my answer, I guess you are using `segue.destinationViewController`, and calling `setDealdetail:` on it. This probably worked fine for your initial segue, because the destinationViewController responded to that message, but, the destination for the new segue doesn't. You need to check which segue is being performed. Using [segue.identifier isEqualToString:MySegueIdentifierString];

Edit 2 (after posting code):

Ok, you need to check which segue is being performed in your `-prepareForSegue:`. Something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueToDealViewControllerIdentifier]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DealViewController *detailView  = (DealViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        detailView.dealdetail = [self.allcontent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailView.dealpostcode = [self.allpostode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailView.dealvenuename = [self.allname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailView.dealaddress = [self.alladdress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailView.dealaddress2 = [self.alladdress2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailView.deallat = [self.alllat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailView.deallng = [self.alllong objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailView.userlatitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserLatitude"];
        detailView.userlongitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserLongitude"];
    }
}
```

Where `SegueToDealViewControllerIdentifier` is the segue identifier for the original segue.

Comment: I have created a prepartForSeague for the first one but not for the second one yet. I thought it would have just moved to the VC without a prepareforseague as thats just for passing variables ? Right or wrong ?

Comment: `prepareForSegue` gets called for any segue you perform - you check in your implementation of it for which segue is being performed: `[segue.identifier isEqualToString:MySegueIdentifierString];`

Comment: Perhaps post your `-prepareForSegue:` code, if that is easier?

Comment: your prepareForSegue should be 
    <if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue identified"]) {
            UIViewControllerClass *controller = (UIViewController     *)segue.destinationViewController;
        }>